# Social Sharing of Game Points in alert (Xcode)

Tags: ios, nstimer, social-framework

I just started programming Apps and so on. So my first App is a "simple" Game with a timer function. My problem is this: I want to give the user a function with it he can share his points on Twitter and Facebook, but the output of the game points are always 0.. I want to fix this and need your help for this.

#### Screenshots

http://techstern.de/app/screenshot1.png 
http://techstern.de/app/screenshot3.png

#### *Sorry, I´m from german, so here's the translation:

"KlickMich" -> "TapMe"
"Zeit" -> "Time"
"Punktestand" -> "Points"
"Die Zeit ist um" -> "Time is up"
"Du hast 11 Punkte erzielt" -> "You scored 11 Points"
"Auf Facebook teilen" -> "Share on Facebook"
"Auf Twitter teilen" -> "Share on Twitter"
"Nochmal spielen" -> "Play again"
"Habe gerade 0 Punkte in KlickMich erreicht..." -> "Just scored 0 points in TapMe..."!

Looking forward to your reactions :)

Yours faithfully
Robin

### Code: ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.m"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;

NSInteger count;
NSInteger seconds;
NSTimer *timer;

int time;
}

- (IBAction) buttonPressed;
- (void)setupGame;
- (void)subtractTime;
- (IBAction)postToTwitter;
- (IBAction)postToFacebook;

@end
```

### Code: ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIAlertView.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self setupGame];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed{
count++;

scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Punktestand: %li",(long)count];

}

- (void)setupGame{
seconds = 15;
count = 0;

timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Zeit: %li",(long)seconds];
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Punktestand: %li",(long)count];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(subtractTime)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

}

- (void)subtractTime{
seconds--;
timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Zeit: %li",(long)seconds];

if (seconds == 0) {
    [timer invalidate];
    
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Die Zeit ist um"
                                                    message:[NSString       stringWithFormat:@"Du hast %li Punkte erzielt",(long)count]
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Nochmal spielen"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Auf Facebook teilen", @"Auf Twitter teilen", nil];
    
    [alert show];
}

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

[self setupGame];

if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
    [self postToTwitter];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 2)
{
    [self postToFacebook];
}
}

- (IBAction)postToTwitter{
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Habe gerade %li Punkte in KlickMich erreicht...",(long)count]];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
} 

- (IBAction)postToFacebook{
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    
    [controller setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Habe gerade %li Punkte in KlickMich erreicht...",(long)count]];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I review your code. You reset your timer first, then you are send score to share on `Twitter`.

First share on `Twitter` and then you have to call `setupGame` method like this :

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
       [self postToFacebook]; 
    }  
    else if (buttonIndex == 2)
    {
       [self postToTwitter];
    }

   [self setupGame]; // after share you can reset
 }
```

And call this method like `-(void)postToTwitter` not like `- (IBAction)postToTwitter`. because there is no connection to that method. you are calling that method not connect with a button action.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I didm´t think the solution would be that easy :D - But one more thing I have: How can I stop the timer while the user posts the points to twitter or Facebook? Because the timer just go´s on when Post to Facebook or Twitter Button was tapped. How can I just let the timer start when "Cancel" or "Post" was clicked? Any Ideas?

Comment: Okay cool, but what do you mean with "some times"? Further 30 minutes?

Comment: Try to call this [self setupGame]; in - (void)postToTwitter method after sharing coding. don't write in "alertView clickedButtonAtIndex" method. If u want to write then write in if (buttonIndex == 0), because it'll return alertview cancel action.

Comment: No sorry, same problem, but how do you mean the second option? In "if (buttonIndex == 0)"?

Answer (score 0):

this is your required answer. Please go through this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if (buttonIndex == 0)
  {
    [self setupGame];
    NSLog(@"Cancel..");
  }
  else if (buttonIndex == 1)
  {
    NSLog(@"Facebook..");
    [self postToFacebook];
  }
  else if (buttonIndex == 2)
  {
    NSLog(@"Twitter..");
    [self postToTwitter];
  }
}
- (void)postToTwitter
{
   SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
//     if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
//     {
     SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block    completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

      [tweetSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        switch(result){
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            default:
            {
                NSLog(@"Cancel");
                [self setupGame];
            }
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            {
                NSLog(@"Post");
                [self setupGame];
            }
                break;
        }
    };

    [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Habe gerade %li Punkte in KlickMich erreicht...",(long)count]];
    [tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
  //}

 }
```